# Writing multiple layers to GeoPackage using writeOGR() in R?

Tags: gdal, r, rgdal, geopackage, sf

I'm trying to write multiple layers to the same GeoPackage in R, but I get an error, `Creation of output file failed`. I have tried to search for documentation of reading and writing to .gpkg files with RGDAL, e.g. to figure out whether `writeOGR()` actually supports multiple layers, with little success. **Is this even possible, if so, how to do it?** Minimal working example:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)

data(wrld_simpl)

norway <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME == "Norway", ]
sweden <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME == "Sweden", ]

file <- tempfile("scandinavia", fileext = c(".gpkg"))

writeOGR(norway, dsn = file, layer = "norway", driver = "GPKG")
writeOGR(sweden, dsn = file, layer = "sweden", driver = "GPKG")

ogrListLayers(file)
```

---

There is apparently an `ogr2ogr` [shell command](https://github.com/rkrug/rGeoPackage/issues/8) that does the trick (hat tip [mdsumner](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1204/mdsumner)), which I can wrap in an R function. However, it would be neat if writeOGR() and/or st_write() in the `sf` package had this built in. I reckon it depends on GDAL's `layer_options`, but there doesn't seem to be an append-type option for GPKG in [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html).

---

I could write a simple wrapper function for `st_write()` but native support in `sf` or `rgdal` would be better.

Comment: Not possible afaik. Try with sf, which I will be happy to explore as well - it's easier to fix than rgdal for one thing

Comment: @mdsumner st_write() in sf gives the same result. I think the lack of an append option in GDAL's layer creation options is the source of the problem for both writeOGR() and st_write().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using the `append` flag on `sf::st_write()`:

```
library(sf)

nc     <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
storms <- st_read(system.file("shape/storms_xyz.shp", package="sf"))

st_write(nc,     "nc.gpkg", "nc")
st_write(storms, "nc.gpkg", "storms", append = TRUE)

st_layers("nc.gpkg")
## Driver: GPKG 
## Available layers:
##   layer_name  geometry_type features fields
## 1         nc  Multi Polygon      100     14
## 2     storms 3D Line String       71      0
```